# Java rule that warns on hiding fields

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, hidden-field, member-hiding

Java allows [hiding fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

> a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field

But it isn't consider a best practice

> we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult to read.

Is there a rule that can warn on hiding fields in IDE or static tool?

I currently use VS code

We want to avoid issues as setting child field and getting parent field by mistake

```
public abstract class Parent {
   protected String a; 
   public abstract String test();
}
public class Child extends Parent {
   protected String a; 
    @Override
    public String test() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [Sonarlint](https://www.sonarlint.org/?gclid=CjwKCAjwh5qLBhALEiwAioodsxuh06uVXwWokt9I-Dvnby1byQ1UEXPgqTjJsUzCRX44phGWwTqQPRoCYosQAvD_BwE) will help you with this. Even if there is not a predefined rule, you can create your own rules.

Comment: @Aris I search for specific rule

Comment: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/confusing/RSPEC-2387

Comment: @Tom my fields aren't static and not private , but protected, added example

Comment: @user7294900 SonarSource will find the Code Smell in the example you provided

Comment: Sorry that i can't understand your question. Is there any errors or warnings about your code?

Comment: The issue is Child is hidding parent's field. In VSCode I don't have a warning about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intellij IDEA:

> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Visibility -> Field name
> hides field in superclass

Answer (score 1):

Both Eclipse and IntelliJ allows you to configure a Warning or even an Error when you are hiding fields. Unfortunately neither runs on my tablet so that you have to lookup the details for yourself.

By the way, I am sure that NetBeans have something similar.

---

For Eclipse, you can look at "Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors>Field declaration hides another field or variable."